# Email from ContactsContract?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the email adress from det ContactsContract like I have done with the ID, NAME and NUMBER. But why can't I get the email this way? How can I get it?

```
int indexColumnId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);
int indexColumnName =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int indexColumnNumber = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
int indexColumnAdress = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.???????
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, the email address is in another "package".
You need to access "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email" and not "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone".

To do that, you need to use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI as uri.

Answer (score 0):

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS is that what you need?

Comment: It's not working! I get a red line below the code with this error message: ADDRESS cannot be resolved or is not a field